# Assigning a custom date with custom label to a contact

Tags: ios, date, abaddressbook, abperson

I have an app that from some reason needs to assign a custom date to the user contacts, The app was out and worked fine. Now I wish to build a swift version of the app.

While testing it on xCode 6, iOS7 + 8 everything looks great, but when testing in a device I see that the date is added as the Anniversary date of the user and without my custom label.

I tried to add the date directly in the native Contacts app and found that new contacts does not have an option to add a custom date.

Testing on Yosemite I still find this option available.

When checking the ABPerson API I found that the API still has the `kABMultiDatePropertyType`

```
// Dates
AB_EXTERN const ABPropertyID kABPersonDateProperty;              
// Dates associated with this person - kABMultiDatePropertyType
```

It is important to note that when saving the new date I do not get any Error and the date is saved but without my custom label which is important as I do not want to override the user Anniversary date.

Any idea why this is happening / any workaround ?

Comment: did you check the documentation for this? There doesn't seem to be anything documenting this particular value within the newest iOS Xcode API documentation. There is a kABDateProperty and kABMultiDateComponentsProperty that you can use though.

Comment: I confirm `kABPersonDateProperty` is still defined in iOS 8.3 SDK in file "ABPerson.h" on line 131.

Comment: @TheCodingArt as Nicolas mentioned, the documentation still mentions kABPersonDateProperty, I do not get any error if I try to assign the date it just won't save it.

Comment: What is the contact source? ActiveSync? iCloud? Certain properties are not saved for certain source types.

Comment: @LeoNatan I am not sure I understand you, but this is a new contact created in the app itself.

Comment: I mean the `ABSourceType` value.

Comment: @LeoNatan I do not specify it, what is the default ?

Comment: The default is according to the device accounts. It's a mess, and I suggest you study how different sources exist/interop, and what data can be saved for each type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77842/discussion-between-shannoga-and-leo-natan).

Comment: I would like to point out that if something is in the header file, but not in the documentation, it's probably something that's currently unsupported. There being a header file value does not in any way confirm existing functionality.

Comment: Interesting challenge but I think I would need more to chew on. 

Can you post the Obj-c that works.  On occasion I have found that bridging to Obj-c (if it is still supported in Obj-c) is the quickest way to get familiar functionality to work and this might be that kind of situation.  But first I would really need to see what code worked and then recode it in swift.